# How to make a proper word searcher with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, loops

I have an assignment where we have to find words in a word search (minus diagonals).

```
M L G Y J U G D T W W I S F P
G Y O H I K O P V F J B J J H
N B I M T M Y W R D J E C A I
I Y M X C U E U Z G U I J Y C
K D P S L R W J I N C N S W T
O P S D I D A B Z I D G D A B
M X D H K E B H U G T S I L G
S G D U Y R V D G N D M L K M
S P X K T W E F P I G E J I T
B U L B C M K I F S I L F N W
Z Q L X H G C J N D I L B G C
M T B W Z L A D A A X Y O K X
A E C Z K F Y V F B U V G A W
Y G O Z E A W J R N S Q J E A
L O I T E R I N G H F I P G R
```

This is the `15x15` word search that we are given as a text file. We must identify the criminal words within the search out of the list:

```
["JAYWALKING", "BURGLARY", "LAUNDERING", "BADSINGING", "REDRUM", "SMOKING", "BEINGSMELLY","CONNING", "SCAMS", "LOITERING"]
```

I have gone through the word search and have identified that the words needing to be found are: redrum, badsinging, beingsmelly, jaywalking, and loitering.

However, in my code, I only get a result of one from each direction: loitering, and jaywalking. I was hoping someone could give me some advice on how to make it fully functional.

```
def crossword():
empty_list = []
crimes = ["JAYWALKING", "BURGLARY", "LAUNDERING", "BADSINGING", "REDRUM", "SMOKING", "BEINGSMELLY",
          "CONNING", "SCAMS", "LOITERING"]
confession = open("confession.txt", "r")
for line in confession:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    new_list = line.split(' ')
    empty_list.append(new_list)

#horizontal
words = []

for i in range(len(empty_list)):
    string_1 = ""
    string_2 = ""
    m = len(empty_list[i])
    for j in range(len(empty_list[i])):
        string_1 = string_1 + empty_list[i][j]
        string_2 = string_2 + empty_list[i][m-1-j]
    for k in range(len(crimes)):
        if crimes[k] in string_1 or crimes[k] in string_2:
            words.append(crimes[k])


#vertical
for i in range(len(empty_list)):
    string_1 = ""
    string_2 = ""
    m = len(empty_list[i])
    for j in range(len(empty_list[i])):
        string_1 = string_1 + empty_list[j][i]
        string_2 = string_2 + empty_list[j][m-1-i]
    for k in range(len(crimes)):
        if crimes[k] in string_1 or crimes[k] in string_2:
            words.append(crimes[k])
            return words

print("Gentleman GoGo is guilty of:")
print(crossword())
```

Comment: First you are returning inside the loop, just before second last print. Which means it will go inside the loop, append and just return the word list. Which would have single entry yes  :/

Comment: also stop using "open" - instead use "with open" construct to avoid errors like in your current code - you never close that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not optimized (it certainly can be done in more performant, higher order ways), but have a look at https://repl.it/repls/DependentBubblyAssignment

I think a very clear and beginner-friendly approach is to create a second list which reorders the columns as rows - then search the columns for matches in the same way as in the rows.

Details to the repl.it code:

`crime in row or crime in row[::-1]` - checks if a `crime` is present either in ltr or rtl `row`

`verticals = ['' for char in slist[0]]` - creates a list filled with empty strings corresponding to the length of the first row (excl. whitespaces thanks to the previous `line.split(' ')`

`verticals[col] += slist[row][col]` - takes the char from the original string from the `col` at `row` and appends it to the current vertical `col` index

For your example data, it finds `['LOITERING', 'SMOKING', 'REDRUM', 'BADSINGING', 'BEINGSMELLY', 'JAYWALKING']`

Comment: Thank you so much. I noticed one error where one of the horizontal words (loitering) was left out in exchange for something that was not there (smoking) when the code was run. I will attempt to fix this. This code is much easier for me to understand than what I was trying to do.

Comment: YW - But are you referring to an error in your input data or in my code (i did not understand that part)?

Comment: I have added some debugging code to https://repl.it/repls/DependentBubblyAssignment - i am not sure where you see that error happening, can you explain?

Comment: If you look at the word search itself, on the bottom horizontal line, you can see the word "loitering". However, the code you have produced returns "smoking" which is not present in the puzzle altogether. The vertical portion produces the expected results, but the horizontal does not.

Comment: I apologize. It is now outputting loitering. I do not know what was going on, and I missed smoking altogether in the vertical section when going through it earlier. Thank you so much.

Comment: Because of `LOITERING` - could be that you opened the link the moment i was refactoring the code a little bit and ran it in that state - but yes, `SMOKING` is in fact in the first column (in reverse order)